# splitting up timeFrom and timeTo into hour intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

I have the following:

```
TimeFrom                    TimeTo
2015-08-04 11:00:00.000     2015-08-04 14:00:00.000
2015-08-04 18:00:00.000     2015-08-04 20:00:00.000
2015-08-04 21:00:00.000     2015-08-04 23:00:00.000
```

I want to create something that gives me all the hour intervals. Like so:

```
TimeFrom                    TimeTo
2015-08-04 11:00:00.000     2015-08-04 12:00:00.000
2015-08-04 12:00:00.000     2015-08-04 13:00:00.000
2015-08-04 13:00:00.000     2015-08-04 14:00:00.000
2015-08-04 18:00:00.000     2015-08-04 19:00:00.000
2015-08-04 19:00:00.000     2015-08-04 20:00:00.000
2015-08-04 21:00:00.000     2015-08-04 22:00:00.000
2015-08-04 22:00:00.000     2015-08-04 23:00:00.000
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this? It seems like something that should be pretty common but could not find anything relating to this.

I have records for many days, almost a year. All individual records(timeFrom, timeTo) are within in same day(they don't span multiple days).

I am using PrestoDB

Comment: Is is possible that an interval spans two different days, like `(TimeFrom, TimeTo)` = `(2015-08-04 11:00:00.000,  2015-08-05 03:00:00.000)`?

Comment: no it is not possible in this data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a numbers table:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('HOUR', i - 1, TimeFrom) AS TimeFrom, 
       DATE_ADD('HOUR', i, TimeFrom) AS TimeTo
FROM (SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
      UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8
      UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
      UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15 UNION ALL SELECT 16
      UNION ALL SELECT 17 UNION ALL SELECT 18 UNION ALL SELECT 19 UNION ALL SELECT 20
      UNION ALL SELECT 21 UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23 UNION ALL SELECT 24
) AS numbers
INNER JOIN mytable ON numbers.i <= DATE_DIFF('HOUR', TimeFrom, TimeTo)
ORDER BY TimeFrom
```

**Note:** The above query uses `DATE_ADD` and `DATE_DIFF` date and time functions documented [**here**](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.86/functions/datetime.html) for PrestoDB.

Comment: Great! What is "mytable" is a subquery itself? Where would I define that subquery? Can I just plug it into where "mytable" is above? Sorry new to SQL syntax.

Comment: @Javier `mytable` is just your table, not a subquery.

Comment: i meant what if* sorry. Say it is a subquery.

Comment: @Javier In that case, yes you can use it in place of `mytable` and use an alias, like `INNER JOIN (SELECT  TimeFrom, TimeTo FROM ... ) AS mytable ON numbers.i <= DATE_DIFF(HOUR, TimeFrom, TimeTo)`.

Comment: I keep getting: Column '"hour"' cannot be resolved on this line: DATE_DIFF(HOUR, TimeFrom, TimeTo)

Comment: @Javier I have no working experience on PrestoDB. I tried answering based on an on-line manual I found. Try adjusting the datetime functions of my query using any reference manual of the system you use.

Comment: @Javier [This](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) is were I read about `DATE_ADD`, `DATE_DIFF` functions.

Comment: Thanks I figured out what was happening. the unit has to be passed as a string.

Comment: @Javier Glad you got it working. I have edited my answer, to pass time units as strings. Is it OK now?

Comment: If you have some time would appreciate help with more complicated query that involves this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906932/sum-totals-utilization-for-each-hour-in-day-for-all-day-in-month/33907120#33907120

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the way to achieve without having another table that would list every hour. If you are limited to a single day you can fake it by constructin it within your query using UNION ALL

```
SELECT h.Hour
  FROM ( SELECT 2015-08-04 00:00:00.000 AS Hour
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 01:00:00.000    
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 02:00:00.000  
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 03:00:00.000  
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 04:00:00.000  
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 05:00:00.000  
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 06:00:00.000  
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 07:00:00.000  
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 08:00:00.000  
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 09:00:00.000  
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 10:00:00.000  
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 11:00:00.000 
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 12:00:00.000 
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 13:00:00.000 
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 14:00:00.000 
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 15:00:00.000 
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 16:00:00.000 
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 17:00:00.000 
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 18:00:00.000 
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 19:00:00.000 
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 20:00:00.000 
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 21:00:00.000 
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 22:00:00.000 
         UNION ALL SELECT 2015-08-04 23:00:00.000 ) AS h
where exists 
(select id from mytable where h>=TimeFrom and h<=TimeTo)
```

Comment: I am not limited to single day. How could I do it with another table? Sorry I am new to SQL. Are you referring to a join?